# how can make simple List in scala?

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, zip

i know zip can compose two list to one list,

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3).zip(List("4", "5", "6"))
res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,4), (2,5), (3,6))
```

however, the 'res0' is not i want. 
i want this,

```
res0: List[Int] = List(1,4,2,5,3,6)
```

maybe i should use some 'indexOF' or 'zipWithIndex' 
but it seems like a more verbose than good 'way'

is there an elegant way to make list like this example?

or do i need to use some ' IF ' ?

Comment: `List(1, 2, 3) zip List("4", "5", "6") flatMap (x => List(x._1, x._2.toInt))` does the job too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want to interleave the two list, also assuming both the list are of same type. If thats the case this should work for you

```
List(1,2,3) zip List(4,5,6) flatMap {case (x,y) => List(x,y)}
```

And output will be

```
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6)
```